# Is it possible to extend GitHub API search result with specified properties?

Tags: rest, github, github-api

I am doing users search, but the result from GitHub does not contain all the information I need.

For example, when searching for users based in `New York` with request:

> `GET https://api.github.com/search/users?q=location:"New York"`

I got back response such as:

```
{
  "total_count": 58317,
  "incomplete_results": false,
  "items": [
    {
      "login": "ry",
      "id": 80,
      "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjgw",
      "avatar_url": "https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/80?v=4",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/ry",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/ry",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/ry/followers",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/ry/following{/other_user}",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/ry/gists{/gist_id}",
      "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/ry/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/ry/subscriptions",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/ry/orgs",
      "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/ry/repos",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/ry/events{/privacy}",
      "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/ry/received_events",
      "type": "User",
      "site_admin": false,
      "score": 1.0
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

I would like to get back also counts for `public_repos` and `followers`.

This info is available, when sending user query:

> `GET https://api.github.com/users/{login}`

```
{
  ...
  "public_repos": 1331,
  "followers": 262,
  ...
}
```

**Is there a way to extend search results with specified properties?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [GraphQL API v4](https://developer.github.com/v4/) using the following request :

```graphql
{
  search(query: "location:\"New York\"", type: USER, first: 100) {
    userCount
    edges {
      node {
        ... on User {
          login
          followers {
            totalCount
          }
          repositories(privacy: PUBLIC) {
            totalCount
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=%7B%0A%20%20search(query%3A%20%22location%3A%5C%22New%20York%5C%22%22%2C%20type%3A%20USER%2C%20first%3A%20100)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20userCount%0A%20%20%20%20edges%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20User%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20login%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20followers%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20totalCount%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20repositories(privacy%3A%20PUBLIC)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20totalCount%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)